# Windows Explorer has stopped Working Error in VDI

Tags: windows

Windows Explorer has stopped Working Error in VDI

I have got new credentials to log into VDI. I have Windows 7 Enterprise edition (4GB and 32 bit OS) and the display language is NETHERLAND when I connect to VDI. I am able to do right click and perform normal windows operation. However when I change the Display langue to ENGLISH, not able to perform right click on desktop or any ICON/FOLDER and says "Windows Explorer stopped working".

Steps tried to fix the error.

Deleted the Winzip, 7 zip related files from registry
Ran Ccleaner to clear the registry files
Updated my Windows security
Installed all relevant updates under control panel windows update
Checked for Virus and performed CHCKDSK
Ran SFC /Scannow command under the user/admin account

However no fix.

When I asked support to reset my VDI account I am able to do right click and everything seems normal again but the language is NETHERLAND and I do not know.

I hope there will be fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. I only changed the display language to English rest every settings in Region and Language options (control Panel) has to be intact. Earlier I was changing the Format and administrative tab settings to ENGLISH.